# why it does not return anything?

Tags: c++, function, return, boolean

I'm doing a programming exercise about converting Fahrenheit to Celsius [C = 5/9 * (F-32)] with some conditions:

1. create a function toCelsiusByReference which takes a temperature by reference, and returns a bool so : bool toCelsiusByReference(float &temperature);
2. change the parameter from Fahrenheit to the equivalent Celsius
3. return true if the parameter was above freezing (>32 F), return false

I did 1 and 2 and I'm stuck with 3 which does not return me anything. I do not understand why?

I'm testing the value 60 F as temperature which should return me true since 60 F > 32 F.

Why my function `bool toCelsiusByReference(float &temperature)` does not return me anything

Here is the code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

bool toCelsiusByReference(float &temperature);

int main()
{
    float temperature = 60;
    toCelsiusByReference(temperature);
    return 0;
}

bool toCelsiusByReference(float &temperature)
{
    float celsius;
    bool status;

    // convert celsius to Fahrenheit
    cout.setf(ios::fixed, ios::floatfield);
    celsius = 5.00 / 9.00 * (temperature - 32);
    // cout << "Degrees C : " << setprecision(2) << celsius << endl;

    // check if temperature (fahrenheit) is freezing (<32) or not
    if (temperature > 32)
    {
        status = true;
    }
    else
    {
        status = false;
    }

    return status;
}
```

Comment: How do you know it doesn't return anything? You don't store the returned value. Unrelated: you can remove the `if` / `else` block and just return `temperature > 32`

Comment: Code looks fine and it does return the status. You are not doing anything in your code with the returned status so you won’t know that. Did you mean to print it out or something?

Comment: This code is like "I sent you the results, did you check your mail?" and you said "No."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic knowledge: you need to use the returned value somehow.

```
...
if (toCelsiusByReference(temperature))
{
  cout << "above 32°F\n";
}
else
{
 cout << "below 32°F\n";
}
cout << "Converted temperature: " << temperature << " °C\n";
...
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case, it would appear that you are not storing what the function (`toCelsiusByReference`) returns: `toCelsiusByReference(temperature);`.

Now, from a coding perspective, I'd recommend some changes. Try to keep your methods as simple as possible. In your case, you are doing a temparature check in your conversion mechanism, which, at least in my opinion, shouldn't be there.
This also makes the name of the method a bit misleading, since `true` or `false` isn't what one would expect from a method called `toCelsiusByReference`.

So in short:

1. In your `toCelsiusByReference` method, return the equivalent value in degrees celcius.
2. In your main, add the logic for the freezing point temperature.

Comment: Also worth separating any input and output concerns.

Comment: @tadman: I'm assuming the print statements are there for debugging purposes, but if not, yeah, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

Store value returned from function

```
int main
{
  ...
  bool b = toCelsiusByReference(...)
}
```